# Changing layout of navigation drawer icon

Tags: java, android

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQ2P.png)

How can I format the navigation drawer icon (seen on the left) so I can move it to the right or add padding?

I've tried changing the format within the styles; however, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Adding padding to it

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you, I ended up using user2713030's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(<Activity>, <DrawerLayout>, R.drawable.main_icon, 0, 0);
```

`drawable/main_icon.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_icon" android:left="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Then adjust the margins `android:left`, `android:right` etc.

Comment: How would I move the action bar title to the right?